# Trimming a video locally on the browser before uploading it

Tags: javascript, video, frontend, video-processing

I am building a video upload service to the cloud, and I want to allow the users to trim the video locally on the browser before they upload it.
Is there a Javascript solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean trim the length of the video or trim the dimensions of the video (or both)?

Comment: I mean trim the length of the video (not cropping)

Comment: Ok, that's straightforward then using this [video trimming](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery#trimming_videos) transformation. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm asking about trimming *before* uploading the video to the cloud. The link you sent only explains how to serve trimmed version of a video already uploaded. Am i wrong?

Comment: You're right, to process the video on the client side you may want to try any of the ffmpeg translations into JS, which are expected to take quite a bit of space, but worth trying.

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising